# iPad Safari IOS 5 window.close() closing wrong window

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile-safari

We have an iPad application that's working on our older iPads.

We open external links using
var x = window.open(url)

at the end of the day, when the user closes this part of the app, we go through all the windows it opened and do x.close() for each one and everything is okie dokie.

Testing on the new iPad with IOS 5 and the lovely tabs,
opening the new windows (although now they open as tabs) is fine, but doing x.close() doesn't seem to necessarily close x, it may close window y or z. Doing x.focus() or y.focus() works just fine, the correct tab comes into focus, but close seems to just pick whatever tab it wants.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Example program:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        //The openWindow array will hold the handles of all open child windows
        var openWindow = new Array();
       var win1;
       var win2;
        //Track open adds the new child window handle to the array.
        function trackOpen(winName) {
            openWindow[openWindow.length]=winName;
        }

        //loop over all known child windows and try to close them.  No error is
        //thrown if a child window(s) was already closed.
        function closeWindows() {
            var openCount = openWindow.length;
            for(r=openCount-1;r>=0;r--) {
                openWindow[r].close();
            }
        }

        //Open a new child window and add it to the tracker.
        function open1() {
            win1 = window.open("http://www.yahoo.com");
            trackOpen(win1);
        }

        //Open a different child window and add it to the tracker.
        function open2() {
            win2 = window.open("http://www.google.com");
            trackOpen(win2);

        }
        //Open whatever the user enters and add it to the tracker
        function open3() {
            var newURL = document.getElementById("url").value;
            var win3= window.open(newURL);
            trackOpen(win3);
        }

    </script>
    <input type="button" value="Open 1" onclick="open1()">
    <input type="button" value="Open 2" onclick="open2()">
    <input type="button" value="Focus 1" onclick="win1.focus()">
    <input type="button" value="Focus 2" onclick="win2.focus()">
    <input type="button" value="Close 1" onclick="win1.close()">
    <input type="button" value="Close 2" onclick="win2.close()">

    URL: <input type="text" id="url"> <input type="button" value="Open URL" onclick="open3()">
    <input type="button" value="Close All" onclick="closeWindows()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to get around this?

Comment: No, I posted this only a few days before the code was due. We told the client we couldn't implement the feature :-/ Unfortunately the code already has window.close() in some places and caused a lovely production issue for us

Answer (score 3):

That did the trick for me (iPad 2 and 3; 3 with iOS 5.1.1)

```
var host=window.opener;
window.focus(); /* solves the iPad3 problem */
window.close(); /* the actual closing we want to achieve... */
/* makes the focus go back to opener on iPad2, fails silently on iPad3 */
try { host.focus(); } catch(e) {}
```

Comment: Invalid try catch statement : Last line should be `try { host.focus(); } catch(e) {}`.

Answer (score 1):

Set focus on the window before closing it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. My initial code would focus on the parent window and then close the current one. This always ends up closing the wrong window. What I did was to remove the `.focus` call and added a small delay to the window.close() and it worked for me. Original source for the delay suggestion - https://twitter.com/#!/gryzzly/statuses/177061204114685952

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve it completely, at least not in iOS 5.1 where you have to click the tab before it's removed.