# window.close() and iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I wrote this code and it works in all browsers except of Safari on iPhone and iPad. Is there another way to close the window?

```
        var newWin=window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url=<?=urlencode($pathFile)?>&text=text', 'Twitter', params);
        setTimeout(
            function()
            {
                newWin.close();
            },
            30000
        );
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987625/ipad-safari-ios-5-window-close-closing-wrong-window) will help you.

Comment: i have tried this, but it does not work

Comment: Keep in mind that Javascript is only executed in windows/tabs that are active. So if a tab is active (current), the other tabs are suspended.

Comment: I already knew it and i ask for another way to close the window

Comment: I updated to iOS v9.3.5 and it started to work

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804730/window-close-doesnt-work-on-ios-8-gm-seed?rq=1).  To summarize, window.close is broken on iOS8 and there is currently no known workaround.