# window.close() doesn't work on iOS 8 GM seed

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, ios8

I am trying to open new tab via `Javascript` using `window.open()`, then using `window.close()` to close, but it seems `window.close()` doesn't work in safari( iOS 8 GM seed). Here is the code:

A.html:

`<button onclick="window.open('./B.html'); return false;">Open B</button>`

B.html:

`<button onclick="window.close();">Close</button>`

I tried several ways like: **setTimeout**, `window.open()` then close, but doesn't help.

Is there any workaround for this situation?

Comment: Yepp. This sucks big time!

It have not been fixed in the released version of iOS 8.0, and I guess this problem will not be fixed in any upcoming version of iOS 8 either. So we will simply have to live with it. Apple is currently in the process of destroying the web.

Comment: @Pinal, how is that a duplicate? Looks completely unrelated

Comment: Yes, I wanted to close another. Sorry.

Comment: I updated to iOS v9.3.5 and it started to work

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There isn't a workaround.

I added a message in our web pages.
'Please close this window if it does not close automatically.'

There is a forum about this issue.
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1044445

Comment: It might be helpful to include the gist of the forum comments on this issue. The Apple dev forums are behind a paywall.

Comment: Posts from that forum: "To clarify, if it is a known bug is there a reference number I can find to study why it is so?  From my limited Google search, Apple had identical problem with initial iOS 7 release then somewhere along the way it got fixed.  It truly is very frustrating to see no workaround out there."

Comment: "I just got an email from Apple Bug Reporter that my issue #
18304977

is now closed since it's a duplicate of 17801001.  However, I can't look up this original issue."

Comment: "iOS 8.0.2 still does not fix this issue. :("

Comment: I believe it might be this one: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137008 (notice `<rdar://problem/17801001>` reference). Looks like it's marked as "fixed".

Comment: @krukid I'm not familiar with reading their bug reports - but I can tell you even though it's marked as fixed, it's not implemented in iOS 8.0.2. Installed today and the problem persists.

Comment: @John, yes, I didn't mean to imply it worked. It's still broken AFAIK. The way I understand it though, this bug may be fixed internally, pending release.

Comment: This bug has not been fixed in iOS 8.1 Beta. My guess is that we'll have to live with this bug for some time forward.

Comment: It's definitely not fixed with the iOS 8.1 production version.

Comment: iOS 8.1.1 fixed this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It might interest you all to know that even Facebook is telling it's users to manually close the popups. Clearly there's no workaround until the fix in iOS 8.1.1 - http://imgur.com/45agRZU.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm that it works for iOS 8.1.1?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.javascript/LSKr2Ld3jkY/f1NOxVnyrxMJ .I found that this answer solve this problem !

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy I can confirm that it works in iOS 9.3.5 after upgrading from 8.1.0 where it didn't work