# self.close() no longer functions on iOS 8?

Tags: javascript, ios8

I have a web page that includes some javascript so that when the user taps the cancel button an app URL is followed and then the page closes itself. It works great on iOS 7, however on iOS 8 the window is no longer closing. Has anyone else seen this or have any ideas around this?

Thanks.

```
document.getElementById("cancel").onclick = function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Disable the link when it's clicked.
    document.getElementById("cancel").onclick = function () { return false; };

   window.location.href = url.cancel;
   self.focus();
   setTimeout("self.close();",1);

   return false;
};
```

Tried changing self.close() to window.close() without affect.

Comment: Don't you mean to do: `setTimeout(function() { self.close(); }, 1);`? Right now you have a string there instead of a function.

Comment: @DavidSherret It is `eval`ed if it's a string. [See the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25804730/1883647)?

Comment: @ajp15243 ah ok, I didn't know that. I think it's preferable to pass in a function instead.

Comment: @DavidSherret Most definitely! The docs even recommend against it.

Comment: In general, it is a bad practice to close windows without the user's permission.