# Opening apps and closing Safari tabs on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

We have an App that accepts donations and per [Apple's guidelines (item 21.2)](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) we can't do this in-app, it must open a webpage in Safari to perform the donation.  We've got that bit working fine, and we can actually automatically invoke the App post donation and put the user right back where they left off.  The trouble is that the Tab in Safari persists when the user returns to Safari later.

Is there a way to open an app from a webpage while simultaneously closing said webpage in Safari?

Comment: You can open an UIWebView inside your application to manipulate buttons in a website, instead of opening safari. If you really want to using safari, take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987625/ipad-safari-ios-5-window-close-closing-wrong-window

Comment: @tyt_g207 Unfortunately we have to pop out to Mobile Safari per Apple's Guidelines.  Sadly that answer refers to a Web App, in our situation a Native App is handing the user off to Safari and then Safari is handing the user back to the App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently the way to do it is via Javascript.  You can set the window location and then immediately close the window.

e.g.

```
window.location = "myapp://?stuff";
window.close;
```

Comment: Does this still work? I tried running this in the Chrome dev-tools console, and got a warning message saying `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.`

Comment: @Qasim - The above code was for Safari/WebKit on iOS only.